# RTSP H.264 IP camera as video source/input in windows

Tags: h.264, rtsp, ip-camera, ffdshow

I'm currently stuck with this problem and I hope somebody can help me out. I'm trying to create some sort of decoder that will convert a video stream that will act as a video input device so I can use it in Wirecast (video streaming program).

At this stage I use mjpeg IP cameras as video sources using [this neat little program](http://alax.info/blog/1216) that allows me to convert a raw IP address:port into a input device, this works perfectly with unlimited cameras but does not support RTSP nor H.264, I have since upgraded a few cameras so I can get access to HD video.

I have tried a number of RTSP source filters from all over the net, and some programs like xpwebcam to get access to their H.264 filter but no luck as yet. I have tried to create my own filter using GraphStudio but it is beyond my understanding.

The IP cameras video feed URL looks like this..

**Video Feed:**
rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/0/video0

where videoX = 0,1,2 for resolution.

**rtsp://user:pass@10.0.0.10/0/video0**

or **rtsp://@10.0.0.10/0/video0** for non-protected cameras, it's a private network so it does not matter, what ever will work.

I can successfully stream the video feed live using VLC but not much else, I'm not sure if there's a way to turn a stream into a input device.

I have been trying to do this for weeks now but had very little luck in getting it to work.

Please help me :)

Comment: You might need to wait until I have enough time to add RTSP option to this DirectShow source filter...

Comment: Do you have a rough idea when you'll have a go at it? I plan to use this new camera this coming weekend.. (Great work on the prog btw)

Comment: From my digging around lots of people have done it but don't want to share their code..

Comment: I have came across this - http://www.datastead.com/products/dsfilters.html maybe it could help?

Comment: I've got it working in GraphStudioNext (RTSP + H.264), now the problem I have is getting it to act as a windows source?

Comment: Yes source filter is not yet a virtual device. The source filter needs to be specifically packaged to be picked up automatically by apps.

Comment: Do you have any resources or links I could use? I need to get this working asap..

Comment: The filter needs to be implemented in a specific way. Ask DataStead if their software is capable of being a virtual device.

Comment: They're asking a silly amount of money ($1450) for something I wrote in a day, I'm not using their filter anymore. I need to do the next process..

Comment: @StoryTeller you said you have done it .... Do you have a working code ?? Then Please share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a professional photographer with many years in the field this question struck me as rather interesting. The answer you are looking for can be found at this site:
http://alax.info/blog/1416

The site lists the update you need for your equipment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no source filter can't you simply read from source and write to a file and have your other program read it from a file simultaneously. I have used such a trick many times on unix. Can't see why it cannot work here.

Comment: If you read the rest of the replies you will find that I have written my own filter now, I just need to find a way to build the rest of the process so it works as input device.