# How to create a new camera source in Java?

Tags: java, camera, driver, java-17, virtual-webcam

I am trying to create a new camera source or driver in java. [There is a similar question based on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842434/create-a-new-camera-source-using-opencv-python-camera-driver-using-python). What am trying to do is that I want a new camera source shown in windows so that all apps can connect to it. And the output will be many images showing in a loop instead of live camera. Can I achieve this with java? If yes How? In stackoverflow there are many questions based on c++. But not about Java. I am trying to achieve this in Java. I think for this I need to use something like directX.

I know how to create the loop of images. But How to create a camera source?

Comment: It is worth adding some relevant code

Comment: @AlexeyR. I don't know where to start. That's why I didn't add code

Comment: Implementing a device driver in Java is challenging. The linked python question is about Linux and solved with the aid of a native library doing the integration. You’d likewise need a Windows device driver which acts as a framework to delegate the actual work to a Java program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you could divide your problem in two parts:

1. Using a tool for creating virtual webcam video source rather than trying to create a driver from scratch. As discussed in many questions, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786524/rtsp-h-264-ip-camera-as-video-source-input-in-windows), you can use the following tool to create a virtual Direct Show source:
   [DirectShow Video Source Filter for JPEG and M-JPEG IP Cameras](http://alax.info/blog/1216)
2. Using another tool like **ffmpeg** to generate a real time mpegts udp stream from your images (as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267629/is-it-possible-to-create-a-video-stream-mpeg-or-mjpeg-from-jpeg-images-that-ar)). That stream is the one that the virtual camera source will read from.

You could even use Java to create the stream on point 2, using some library like [this](https://github.com/taktik/mpegts-streamer) (not tested by me).

Comment: Sir can you explain with more details